# Getting A Window To Scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want the window to scroll based on size of content, not size of window.  Currently the scrollbar only appears if the window height is less than the specified height in the XAML.  Here is the XAML code. Based on other threads here I tried various things like wrapping the ScrollViewer in a grid.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <src:ObservableSwitches x:Key="Switches"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="ModuleStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="RedModuleStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ModuleStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>


</Window.Resources>

<ScrollViewer IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,-211.4,-168">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="StackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,188.6,114">

        <StackPanel.Resources> 
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelStyle">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>



            <Label Content="Switch Name:" Name="Label1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <Label Content="Software Version:" Name="Label2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Label Content="Model Number:" Name="Label3" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
        <Label Content="IP Address:" Name="Label4" HorizontalAlignment="left"></Label>
        <Label Content="Serial Number:" Name="Label5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
        <Label Content="Show Tech Taken:" Name="Label6" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>

    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="105,0,218,489">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Label Content="{Binding switchName}"  Name="SwitchNameLabel" HorizontalAlignment="left" />
        <Label Content="{Binding swVersion}" Name="VersionLabel" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding switchModel}" Name="ModelNumberLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding IPAddress}" Name="IPAddressLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding SerialNumber}" Name="SerialLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding LastDataCaptureDate}" Name="ShowTechLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Name="ContentPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TreeView Name="ModulesTreeView" Height="auto" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="auto"/>
        <TreeView Name="VSANTreeView"  Height="auto" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="auto"/>
        <TreeView Name="FCIPTreeView"   MaxHeight="200" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <TreeView Name="IVRTreeView" Height="Auto" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <TreeViewItem Name="IVRTreeViewItem" Header="IVR Topology" Height="Auto" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto">

                <TreeViewItem Name="NatEnabled" Header="NAT Enabled" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto">
                <Label Name="NATLabel" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto"></Label>

                </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Name="Status" Header="Status" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto">
                <Label Name="StatusLabel" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto"></Label>

            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Name="FabricDistributionEnabled" Header="Fabric Distribution" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto">
                <Label Name="FabricDistributionLabel" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto"></Label>

            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Name="AFID" Header="AFID Listing" Background="GhostWhite" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto">
                <ListView Name="AFIDListView" >

                </ListView>
            </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Is this wpf?  Can't tell from just your xaml.

Comment: Yes, this is WPF.  added a tag.  Sorry.

Comment: By scroll do you mean have the scrollbar show up or do you mean you want the content to have a fixed height and thus there is always something to scroll?

Comment: I want the scrollbar to show up.  Rigth now if the window is taller than the height set in XAML, there is content cut off by the bottom of the window and I can't scroll down to it.  I can make the window taller but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: You have no outer grid and multiple stack panels in and inner grid.  Back up to to the back.  Grid with one ScrollViewer and one StackPanel.

Comment: @Blam - Geez.  That easy.  I was trying to keep things organized with the multiple stakpanels. Thanks.  If you post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no outer grid and multiple stack panels in an inner grid. Back up to the basics. Grid with one ScrollViewer and one StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if I wrap the  in the ScrollViwer rather than having the ScrollViewer inside the Grid I can have whatever I want in the Grid and the Window will still scroll properly.